# Aurelia and models in ASP.net core

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, aurelia

I've been exploring different javascript frameworks lately and decided to start to rewrite an ASP.Net Core MVC frontend using Aurelia.
I used the [SPA template](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) to start over.

Everything works fine, I have loaded my DAL, BLL projects along, set up my connection to my database using EF core and pulling out data into my Aurelia front end.

However, for the time being, in my ts files, i am using interfaces which are almost identical to the models I have set up in my BLL.

My model:

```
public class staff
    {        
        [Key]
        public short StaffId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First name *")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Family name *")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Phone")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Birth Date"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }  
    }
```

Aurelia interface in my ts file

```
interface staff{
    firstname: string;   
    familyname: string;
    phone: string;
    date: date;
}
```

I would like to avoid redundancy and would like to use the models directly instead.
Is there a way to do so by importing/injecting the models into my ts files?
Even better can i use the annotations for setting the titles of my tables in the html or to to do some formatting/validation?

Thank you

Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

Although, initially, it may seem like a good idea to have your aurelia models generated from your backend models, it removes a large benefit of using an SPA.

You should treat both your backend and aurelia front end as distinct applications. Your view models are never going to be completely identical to your domain and keeping them separated means a whole rewrite of either doesn't affect the other one.

You should implement a mapping mechanism to map your domain models to aurelia models before sending them over the wire. (I suggest automapper if you don't want to implement yourself)

From experience, your aurelia models will slowly diverge from your domain as features are added. You'll start to have properties in your view that are generated on the fly during mapping, normally as an aggregation of other properties. This can cause a great deal of pain if you're trying to fit these properties into your domain (where they shouldn't be!) I know the duplication seems like overhead but having your frontend depending directly on your backend brings a much larger overhead.